# "ValueError: Protocol message DeidentifyTemplate has no 'deidentifyTemplate' field."

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to create DE-identification template using GCP DLP API client library(Python 3). I have successfully created de-identification template using POST method. What the DE-identification template dose is encrypt some PII fields using Google KMS wrapped Key.

```
      client.create_deidentify_template(
          parent=parent,
          deidentify_template=deidentify_template,
          template_id=templateId,
          retry=google.api_core.gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT,
          timeout=google.api_co
          re.gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT,
          metadata=None)
```

Error:

> **ValueError**: Protocol message DeidentifyTemplate has no 'deidentifyTemplate' field.

Comment: exception ValueError: Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deidentify_template: DLP api take field name not field type.
for example :

```
{
    "display_name" : "de_identification_template",
    "description" : "masking sensitive data",
    "deidentify_config" : {
             "info_type_transformations" : {
                      #your specification here.
                }

}
```

you must change "deidentifyConfig" to  "deidentify_config" for you python DLP api call.

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-templates-deid is quite misleading. it's only for web DLP API POST, not for python client library.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your parameter `deidentify_template=deidentify_template` is the problem.
From [Google DLP API Python Client](https://googleapis.dev/python/dlp/latest/gapic/v2/api.html#google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient.create_deidentify_template) documentation:

**deidentify_template** (Union[dict, DeidentifyTemplate]) – The DeidentifyTemplate to create.

If a dict is provided, it must be of the same form as the protobuf message DeidentifyTemplate

For how [DeidentiftTemplate is defined](https://googleapis.dev/python/dlp/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#google.cloud.dlp_v2.types.DeidentifyTemplate) it you are missing some paremeters:

**display_name**
Display name (max 256 chars).

**description**
Short description (max 256 chars).

**create_time**
The creation timestamp of a inspectTemplate, output only field.

**update_time**
The last update timestamp of a inspectTemplate, output only field.

**deidentify_config**
///////////// // The core content of the template // ///////////////

**create_time**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.create_time

**deidentify_config**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.deidentify_config

**description**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.description

**display_name**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.display_name

**name**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.name

**update_time**
Field google.privacy.dlp.v2.DeidentifyTemplate.update_time

Comment: most of the parameters here are optional and response format after API call.